# knockoutjs function argument ordering

Tags: knockout.js

I want some confirmation regarding the argument ordering in knockout js method binding

SituationA: if I only send in $data and event, then the first argument is data, second argument is dom event

```
<a data-bind="click: $root.myFunction.bind($data)" href="#">Add Sheet</a>
self.myFunction = function (data, event) {}
```

SituationB: if I send in extra parameter, then $data becomes the last parameter in myFunction, while myparam holds the value for "funnyworld"

```
<a data-bind="click: $root.myFunction.bind($data,'funnyworld')" href="#">Add Sheet</a>
self.myFunction = function (myparam, data) {}
```

do I understand the arugment order correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Situation A:**

```
$root.myFunction.bind($data)
```

Would cause the `this` in `myFunction` to be the current view-model (`$data`). The usual arguments will be passed by Knockout as well, so your arguments would actually be:

```
self.myFunction = function (arg1, arg2) {
      // this === $data
      // arg1 === $data
      // arg2 === event
}
```

**Situation B:**

```
$root.myFunction.bind($data, 'funnyworld')
```

Would also cause the `this` in `myFunction` to be the current view-model (`$data`) but will also make the first argument `'funnyworld'`:

```
self.myFunction = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
      // this === $data
      // arg1 === 'funnyworld'
      // arg2 === $data
      // arg3 === event
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a data-bind="event: { 'click': myFunction.bind($data, 'param1', 'param2') }" href="#">Add Sheet</a>

var vm = {
    myFunction: function (firstParam, secondParam, data, e) { 
        console.log(firstParam);
        console.log(secondParam);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(e);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Console will print:

```
param1
param2
Object {myFunction: function}...
MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null, toElement: a, fromElement: null, y: 15, x: 46…}...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nWm5J/

Comment: i use the syntax $root.myFunction.bind everywhere, therefore the other answer is more closed to what I need, I test your code, it works as well, thanks